# iPhone application compatibility

Tags: iphone, compatibility, ios, health.app

Does the [Nike iPhone Sport Kit](http://www.apple.com/ipod/nike/) will work on a 2nd generation iPhone that has the 3.0 update applied? In the Q&A on the website, some say it will, but others say it only works on a 3GS iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

The Nike iPhone Sport Kit [only works on the iPhone 3GS and later](http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeos/p/nikeplus/en_US/support?2#/faqs/article/1878).

It won't work on the first iPhone or on the iPhone 3G.